# Paypal get susbcription details with PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I'm trying to fetch Subscription details by its Subscription ID, but i'm unable to get it. It raised this error: {"name":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","message":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v1/#error-INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","debug_id":"9fc43dc5ea630"}

Below is my code:

```
$accessToken='A21AAEk8KaihyonOUmmnSsx_2MLCXocZIMHjRxJreQtQ8Tck7fpxC_Q17u-OPRlnAdYWHRRwbiz-hLfBlbOJj_7SwOYVDoOaw';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-BW452GLLEP1G");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$result = json_decode($response);
print_r($response);

[![Error Screenshot][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcvlW.png
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Error: {"name":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","message":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v1/#error-INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","debug_id":"9fc43dc5ea630"}

Comment: Check it please - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_create

Comment: I'm not so perfect in PHP and APIs, can you please guide me a little to add these actions or call cURL?

Comment: Could you please show more code

Comment: @Dmitry i have updated the code in description please check and if you can help me out here?

Comment: Paypal doesn’t seem to recognize the resource ID you are passing. Since there are no other parameters here, I assume that can only be referring to the `I-BW452GLLEP1G` part of the URL then(?) - so double-check that is correct.

Comment: @04FS yes i checked the code twice, but didn't found anything else, only this error

Comment: @04FS you can also check this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcvlW.png error

Comment: So where does `I-BW452GLLEP1G` come from then?

Comment: It is the subscription ID where i'm getting user's recurring payments. There are multiple subscription IDs, this is one of them.

Comment: **[You should not switch off `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` or `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/10/certainty-automated-cacert-pem-management-for-php-software)**. It could be a security risk! [Here is how to get the certificate bundle if your server is missing one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32095378/1839439)